# Accessing object properties in blade when using table

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a form where an Admin can create text and also use objects as used in Blade.  I want to store the text in a table and then display it in HTML with the objects working properly.

For example, I would have a form with this input in my view

```
  <div class='form-group'>
    <textarea placeholder="" name='comments' type='' rows='10' class='form-control' id='' value = '{{ old('comments') ?? $plansubmission->comments }}'>{{ $plansubmission->comments }}</textarea>
    <div>{{ $errors->first('comments') }}</div>
  </div>
```

In that form input, I have entered the following:

```
Dear Employee,  {{ $plansubmission->id }}
```

This input validates and the input is sent to comments column in the proper table in my database.

Now, I want to return the comments column back into the view with all the spacing that was submitted into the input (therefore, I use the 'pre' tags):

```
<pre> {{ $plansubmission->comments}}  </pre>
```

The plan text and spacing is maintained but the blade part simply comes out as {{ $plansubmission->id}} instead of what the actual property is.

Comment: What is the file name for the view? it should be `view_name.blade.php`. The `*.blade.php` Is what tells Laravel to enable blade processing.

Comment: the filename is a .blade.php.  I think when the blade helpers come from a table it removes their functionality.  Trying to figure out how to get that functionality back

Comment: What do you mean when they come from a table? You should post more code so we can get an idea of how the view/variables are assembled.

Comment: Oh I see what you're doing now. You're trying to make it so someone can enter a comment that displays a value from the submission model? The blade processing is done based on the content of the blade file, not the content of the variables used. In order to do what you're trying you need to add an additional processing step before sending the data to the view to process any variables included in the comment. You need to be VERY careful with this as they way you're trying to do it now can potentially expose way more than you intend. You shouldn't let users submit arbitrary blade templates.

Comment: yes, exactly.  thanks.  yes, I wasn't sure if there was a way around this.  I think I may change how I am doing this because of security risks

Comment: I submitted an answer that should work for what you're wanting to do. It does require pulling in a package to do the processing. I've used it before and it works pretty well.

Comment: Does my answer point you in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

It's a major security problem to let users submit blade templates to display data. Blade is compiled to PHP so you would be essentially allowing users to execute any PHP code they want. I would recommend you use something like [mustache](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php) to let users inject variables into the output.

In the controller that passes the data to the view, you can pass the `$plansubmission->comments` through a mustache parser. This will treat the comments field as a template, and the second parameter sets the variables that the template has access to. This way you can explicitly set what the comment template has access to so you don't let users leak more data than is required.

```
$m = new Mustache_Engine;
$comments = $m->render($plansubmission->comments, $plansubmission->toArray());
```

Then users can put something like this in the comments field

```
Dear Employee,  {{ id }}
```

Then in the view do

```
<pre> {{ $comments }} </pre>
```

and it will output

```
<pre> Dear Employee,  123  </pre>
```